# How to change text in widget on button click in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to change the text in this widget when the button is clicked.

That is, every time I click on the button, the text changes to what is in the first column of my lit. First the first line, then the second line, and so on until the end.

Here is the code:

```
// CSV Experiment route
class CSVExperimentRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const CSVExperimentRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'CSV Experiment',
      home: ListFromCSV(),
    );
  }
}

class ListFromCSV extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState createState() => _ListFromCSVState();
}

class _ListFromCSVState extends State<ListFromCSV> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _data = [];

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _loadCSV() async {
    final _rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> _listData =
    const CsvToListConverter().convert(_rawData);
    setState(() {
      _data = _listData;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("My CSV Attempt"),
      ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: _loadCSV,
                      child: const Text('Click me to change Text'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const YetAnotherRoute()),
                        );
                      },
                      child: const Text('Button 2'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CSVRoute()),
                        );
                      },
                      child: const Text('Button 3'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              // Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              // Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              // Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Item from CSV',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        )
      // Display the contents from the CSV file
      // body: ListView.builder(
      //   itemCount: _data.length,
      //   itemBuilder: (_, index) {
      //     return Card(
      //       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
      //       color: index == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
      //       child: ListTile(
      //         leading: Text(_data[index][0].toString()),
      //         // title: Text(_data[index][1]),
      //         // trailing: Text(_data[index][2].toString()),
      //       ),
      //     );
      //   },
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is a schematic representation of what I want:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit1. If added to text

```
Text(
                      _data[0].toString() != null ? 
                      _data[0].toString() : '',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )
```

, then I get the following error:

[image]

Edit2. Here is a sample of how the .csv file looks like for testing purposes. This is a list of lists.

[Example](https://mega.nz/file/xg51QSIA#e9cufDVBx3HjrZfhGDx_BOX3HsFFL1HfS6HIy7f3qmc)

Edit3. Given that I was not working correctly with the list of lists, I made the changes that Ghilherme wrote about. And now I get a blank screen.
[image]

Edit4. Ghilherme's code is absolutely correct:

```
class CSVExperimentRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const CSVExperimentRoute({key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'CSV Experiment',
      home: ListFromCSV(),
    );
  }
}

class ListFromCSV extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState createState() => _ListFromCSVState();
}

class _ListFromCSVState extends State<ListFromCSV> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _data = [
    [""]
  ];
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _loadCSV() async {
    List<dynamic> test = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"];
    List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [];
    _listData.add(test);

    setState(() {
      _data = _listData;
      _listCount < test.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
              ? _isFirstLoad = false
              : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("My CSV Attempt"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: _loadCSV,
                      child: const Text('Click me to change Text'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Button 2'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Button 3'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              // Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              // Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              // Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      _data[0][_listCount],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
        // Display the contents from the CSV file
        // body: ListView.builder(
        //   itemCount: _data.length,
        //   itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        //     return Card(
        //       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
        //       color: index == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
        //       child: ListTile(
        //         leading: Text(_data[index][0].toString()),
        //         // title: Text(_data[index][1]),
        //         // trailing: Text(_data[index][2].toString()),
        //       ),
        //     );
        //   },
        // ),
        );
  }
}
```

The only problem is that I make a mistake when I try to change his test list to my list of lists from csv. As a result, when the button is clicked, I see the first entry, but subsequent clicks do not show the text at all.:

```
// This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _loadCSV() async {
    // List<dynamic> test = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"];
    final _rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
      // List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [];
    List<List<dynamic>> _listData =
    const CsvToListConverter().convert(_rawData);
    // _listData.add(test);

    setState(() {
      _data = _listData;
      _listCount < _data.length - 1 //_data instead of test
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing List of List in the wrong way. The correct way would be something like this:  `_data[0][_listCount];`

A better approach would be: (EDIT: I have put all the code now)
EDIT2: I am putting all code to use with CSV load file.

```
class CSVExperimentRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const CSVExperimentRoute({key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'CSV Experiment',
      home: ListFromCSV(),
    );
  }
}

class ListFromCSV extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState createState() => _ListFromCSVState();
}

class _ListFromCSVState extends State<ListFromCSV> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [
    [""]
  ];
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;

  @override
  initState() {
    _loadCSV();
  }

  // This function is only triggered at init, so we only load csv once
  void _loadCSV() async {
    String _rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("dummy.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(_rawData);
  }

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData[0].length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
              ? _isFirstLoad = false
              : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("My CSV Attempt"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: _nextCSV,
                      child: const Text('Click me to change Text'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Button 2'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Button 3'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              // Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                              // Color(0xFF1976D2),
                              // Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      _listData[_listCount][0],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what went wrong. But after I pasted your code, this screen went blank. Not even buttons. Screenshot is in edit3.

Comment: It is not to paste but to make adjustments based in the code I provided. As I said in the answer, I have shortened some part of the code to make a better clarification in how to access an List of List. Try to focus on the TExt widget and _loadCSV() method and the scoped variables

Comment: @Texter I have pasted the entire code now. You should be able to paster and run with this example now.

Comment: Yes, your code is working. Thanks a lot. Please tell me how to modify it for my needs. I mean I took out your test list and put in my list of lists from csv. But then I make a mistake where I only see the first line on the first click of the button and nothing on subsequent clicks. I added the modified code to Edit4.

Comment: @Texter I have pasted the code working with the CSV file you provided. Notice that we have 2 functions now. One is to load csv only one time at initState, and the other is to change the text based on csv value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, it works perfect! It will take me a while to realize this magic, haha.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you can simply access the list on index 0 if this is your correct data.

```
Text(
                      _data[0].toString() != null ? 
                      _data[0].toString() : '',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the error I wrote about in the end. I just edited my post.

It turns out that I must first load the csv file when I turn on the device. Otherwise, the application refers to something that does not yet exist.

Comment: you could use a ternery expression to avoid the error, I updated my code

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting exactly the same error. I am a newbie so I am trying to figure it out by starting with code that works and adding what I need. But at the moment I can't do anything.